# Can we connect to databricks remotely using REST APIs (Without databricks connect)

Tags: r, databricks, azure-databricks, sparkr

i want to connect to databricks from a remote server using R studio, can we do it without databricks connect?... is it possible to connect using databricks REST APIs and use sparkR/sparklyR operations after connecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot connect to databricks remotely using REST APIs without databricks-connect.

> You can use [databricks-connect](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html): Databricks Connect allows you to connect your favorite IDE (IntelliJ, Eclipse, PyCharm, RStudio, Visual Studio), notebook server (Zeppelin, Jupyter), and other custom applications to Databricks clusters and run Apache Spark code.

With databricks-connect you can connect your favorite IDE to your Databricks cluster. This means that you can now link, test, and package the code that you want to run on Databricks more easily.

For more details, refer [Test Code in Databricks Notebooks](https://menziess.github.io/howto/test/code-in-databricks-notebooks/).